# Kafka Connect S3 - JSON to Parquet

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Does Kafka Connect S3 support from ***JSON to Parquet***? Appreciate available and alternative suggestions using Kafka Connect S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Kafka Connect S3 support from JSON to Parquet?

No, it does not. Per the [docs page](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html#s3-object-formats):

> You must use the `AvroConverter` with ParquetFormat in the S3 Sink connector. **Attempting to use the `JsonConverter` (with or without schemas) will result in a runtime exception.**

One option you have would be use to [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-16&utm_term=rmoff-devx) to reserialise your data into Avro first, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE STREAM source (COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 INT, COL3 BIGINT) WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KAFKA_TOPIC='my_source_topic');

CREATE STREAM target WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_target_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM source;
```

With that done you then sink `my_target_topic` to S3 using the Parquet formatted (you can even do this from ksqlDB with `CREATE SINK CONNECTOR…`)